# How can I send strings between Intents?

Tags: android, string, android-intent

I need help to send a string to another activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myInt = new Intent(this,Receiver.class);
    myInt.putExtra("key",Event);
    startActivity(myInt);
}

Button b;
EditText Edt;
String Event;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdtText);
        Event=new String(Edt.getText().toString());             
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thats the intent with the String Event which I want to send to this Activity

```
public class Receiver extends Activity {

TextView txtV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receiving);
    txtV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtV);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        String value = extras.getString("key");
    }
    txtV.setText("key");
}
}
```

When I run my program it only shows me "key" but I want to show the String event which I can't use in this activity although I used the putExtra method in the first intent. 
Please help me, I know there are many others similar questions like that but I still don't get it.

Comment: what event are u talking about?

Comment: use  `txtV.setText(value);` instead of `txtV.setText("key");`  inside if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I hope it will help you.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    Edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EdtText);
    Event=new String(Edt.getText().toString()); //Remove this line   
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Event = Edt.getText().toString();  //Write here
    Intent myInt = new Intent(this,Receiver.class);
    myInt.putExtra("key",Event);
    startActivity(myInt);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receiving);
    txtV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtV);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        String value = extras.getString("key"); //assign it.
        txtV.setText(value); //set it to textview.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but it sill doesnt run it always shows key instead of the string i want

Comment: @Marques Do it carefully whatever I told you above. once again implement this.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
    txtV.setText(value);
```

Not this:

```
    txtV.setText("key");
```